# How to integrate Jenkins with Jest or other test library for Node?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, continuous-integration, jestjs, continuous-deployment

I've made a **GitLab CE** and **Jenkins** integration in a local server. I would like to know how I can integrate Jenkins with **Jest** for generate reports or logs about the test results. If any of the tests failed, Jenkins  should not continue and should notify me. I've already integrated **Slack** for the notifications and placed some commands in Jenkins like: `npm install`, `npm run test`, but still Jenkins doesn’t know if there’s tests or not.

**Jenkins configuration:**

[image: Jenkins project configuration]

The flow should be the following:

1. I make a change in the master repository
2. Gitlab runs the webhook that invokes Jenkins
3. Jenkins brings the new changes, build and run tests
4. If some of the tests failed should send a Slack notification otherwise, should create a docker image

Any suggestion or correction is welcome

Comment: have do you solved this?

Comment: @SandipPingle Not yet :(